# ADO.NET Entity Data Model forcecloses after "Choose Your Data Connection"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model, mysql.data

So I am trying to create my ADO Entity data model, and i cant seem to get past the "choose your data connection" page.  I choose the correct connection, then click either no or yes for sensitive data, and i click next.  However, nothing appears.  There is no error message like the common "your project references the latest version of entity framework however an entity framework database provider."  It just closes the prompt and returns me to my project.

Has anyone ever seen this before?

Comment: remove the mysql.*.dll references and add them back manualy

Comment: No, make sure to install the latest Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx

Comment: Also, make sure you have the latest service pack for you windows machine.

Comment: Finally make sure you the latest Entity Framework installed (6.1.2 as of 5/5/2015) on you project:    "install-package entityframework"

Comment: Where you able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you have such a problem, make sure that the version of the NuGet MySQL EF package matches the version of the MySQL Connector for NET